# DataGrid ItemsSource to DataTable to CSV

Tags: c#, wpf, csv, datagrid, datatable

I have a `DataTable` that provides items to a `DataGrid`. The `DataTable` is populated from a `CSV` file. I allow the user to add new rows but I am unsure of how to update the `DataTable`, then use that to update the `CSV`.

To begin with I believe I should be using the `RowEditEnding` event on the `DataGrid` itself. This is what I have tried;

```
private void OnRowEditEnding(object sender, DataGridRowEditEndingEventArgs e)
{
    var dataTable = new DataTable();
    var itemsSource = subbieDataGrid.ItemsSource as IEnumerable;
    foreach (var item in subbieDataGrid.Items)
    {
        dataTable.Rows.Add(item);
    }
    CommonEngine.DataTableToCsv(dataTable, @"C:\Users\dand\Desktop\Subcontractors.csv", ',');
}
```

However I have two issues with what I have done here. Firstly it doesn't work as an error is thrown saying the array is longer than the `DataTable`.

Secondly, I think it is inefficient to create an entirely new `DataTable` and add the original items plus the new one to it when I could use the original `DataTable`, just add the new item to it and update the `CSV` file using the `DataTable`.

However, I am unsure of how to do this.

Answer (score 2):

I hope  you can skip this step, it's not recommended

```
foreach (var item in subbieDataGrid.Items)
{
    dataTable.Rows.Add(item);
}
```

This is the way to transfer all the records from  `Datagrid` to `Datatable` without using the LOOP

```
 DataTable previewForexcel = new DataTable();
                previewForexcel = ((DataView)DatabaseGrid.ItemsSource).ToTable();
```

Try this good luck!